# Restore Tab Focus From CEFSharp

Tags: wpf, focus, cefsharp

I have a WPF application that hosts a CEF browser using CEFSharp. I've found that if I navigate my application's controls using keyboard tabbing, I can cycle through my controls without problem. Once focus makes it to the `ChromiumWebBrowser` control, focus shifts to within the current web page, as expected. However, once focus makes it within the web page, I can never get focus back out to my application. Hitting tab at the end of the html document just moves focus back to the top of the page, rather than pushing focus back to my application.

I have tried implementing `IFocusHandler`, but `IFocusHandler.OnSetFocus()` gets called right when the application is launched and none of the handler methods ever get called again.

How can I move focus back to the host application when tabbing reaches the end of a document in CEFSharp?

**UPDATE:**

Since this is a bug in CEF that has yet to be fixed, here are a couple relevant links to check on later to see if any progress has been made.

CEFSharp issue: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/721

CEF issue: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1826/focus-handler-not-called-for-offscreen

Comment: Known problem for which there is currently no workaround unfortunately. It's a bug in `CEF` (`CefSharp` is just a wrapper). The `OnTakeFocus` method is never called when using `Offscreen Rendering`, which is what the `WPF` control uses.

Comment: @amaitland, that's unfortunate. Do you know if there's a specific issue logged in the CEF project for this? I'd like to at least follow along with any progress being made. When I searched, I found one that sounded the same but quickly turned into an OSX-specific issue in the comments.

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific issue, best to ask for clarification on `ceforum`. http://magpcss.org/ceforum/ Problem is likely similar in nature to the OSX one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll bring my question there.